# Getting error cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

In my project I am trying to build framework using (Cucumber + TestNG + Maven) but during designing baseclass and integrating with pageobjects in other class the issue of cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class arised,

In my structure I am using baseclass consisting of methods for the invocation of browser instance, teardown of browser and then accesssormethods to access browser instance across different classes

Then, in my other class, I have my pageobjects along with constructor to initialize the pageobjects

Thirdly, I have a class consisting of stepdefintion class which corresponds to feature file and in the step definition class I declared the instance of baseclass and my pageobjects class and then passing the driver through accessor methods of baseclass but despite of that my code is not working please refer code below and feature file in attachment:-

**Baseclass Code**:-

```
public class Basehelper {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected  NgWebDriver ngdriver;

    @Before
    public void initializebrowser()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        ngdriver= new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://rmi.com/");
        ngdriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        driver.findElement(ByAngular.model("username")).sendKeys("rmidev");
        driver.findElement(ByAngular.model("password")).sendKeys("rmidev");
        driver.findElement(ByAngular.buttonText("Submit")).submit();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

@Before("@selectdistrict15")
    public void changetodistrict15()
    {
        ngdriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mainMenu_changeDistrictMenu")).click();
        ngdriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",driver.findElement(By.id("changeDistrictMenu_jmsRusselMetals")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("changeDistrictMenu_jmsRusselMetals")).click();
        ngdriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        driver.findElement(By.id("jmsRusselMetals_DistTo15-JmspBlytheville")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("app_previous")).click();
        ngdriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
    }

@After
    public void teardown() 
    {
      driver.close();     
    }

    public  WebDriver getbaseclassdriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }

    public NgWebDriver getbaseclassngdriver()
    {
        return ngdriver;
    }
```

**Stepdefinition class**

```
public class IM801CLPageDefintion  {

    Basehelper h=new Basehelper();
    IM801CLPageObjects obj=new IM801CLPageObjects(h.getbaseclassdriver());
    @When("^we navigate menu$")
    public void we_navigate_menu() throws Exception {
       obj.Inventorymenu.click();
      h.getbaseclassngdriver().waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        ((JavascriptExecutor)h.getbaseclassdriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",obj.InventoryExceptionMenu);
        obj.InventoryExceptionMenu.click();
        h.getbaseclassngdriver().waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        obj.TaggedcostMenu.click();
    }

    @Then("^click on enter button$")
    public void click_on_enter_button() {
    h.getbaseclassngdriver().waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
      obj.Enterbutton.click();
    }

    @Then("^click on return to main menu$")
    public void click_on_return_to_main_menu() {
        h.getbaseclassngdriver().waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
         obj.returnbutton.click();
    }

    @When("^remove the district field value$")
    public void remove_the_district_field_value() {
         obj.DistrictField.clear();
    }
}
```

**Runner class:-**

```
package runner;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(features={"src//test//resources//featurefiles"},glue= {"im801clsteps"},plugin={"html:target/cucumber-html-report",
        "json:target/cucumber.json", "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt"})

@Test
public class MainRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests
{

}
```

[Featurefile attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9eCP.png)

please refer here for console logs:-

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.10.0
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\keshavd\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--2074603226\testng-customsuite.xml


[31mFailed scenarios:[0m
[31mIM801CL.feature:7 [0m# Scenario: To test the functionality of IM801CL program on district 35
[31mIM801CL.feature:13 [0m# Scenario: To test the functionality of IM801CL program on district 99

2 Scenarios ([31m2 failed[0m)
9 Steps ([31m2 failed[0m, [36m7 skipped[0m)
0m0.081s

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class im801clsteps.IM801CLPageDefintion
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.runBackground(CucumberScenario.java:59)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:42)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:41)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at im801clsteps.IM801CLPageDefintion.<init>(IM801CLPageDefintion.java:12)
    ... 41 more

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class im801clsteps.IM801CLPageDefintion
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.runBackground(CucumberScenario.java:59)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:42)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:41)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at im801clsteps.IM801CLPageDefintion.<init>(IM801CLPageDefintion.java:12)
    ... 41 more

FAILED: feature(To test the functionality of IM801CL program)
        Runs Cucumber Feature
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class im801clsteps.IM801CLPageDefintion
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:69)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class im801clsteps.IM801CLPageDefintion
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.runBackground(CucumberScenario.java:59)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:42)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:41)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at im801clsteps.IM801CLPageDefintion.<init>(IM801CLPageDefintion.java:12)
    ... 41 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@35645047: 10 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 8 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@5b367418: 6 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@46b61c56: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@12d2ce03: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@3d9c13b5: 19 ms
```

Comment: You do not need a Test annotation on the runner class. The AbstractTestNGCucumberTests contains the appropriate Test method. Also what is line no 12 in IM801CLPageDefintion.java which is throwing an NPE? My guess the driver is not initialized...

Comment: Please suggest how should I change my code and  please share your suggested code